# Size limit of varchar(MAX) in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have a row that contains a field defined as `varchar(MAX)`. I'm confused about the limit of the field: in some places, I read that varchar(MAX) has a size limit of 8K and in other places it seems that the limit is 2GB.

I have a string that I want to save to a database; it's about 220K. I'm using linq-to-sql and when the write query submits to the database, the row gets written without any exceptions generated. However, when I open the database table in SSMS, the cell that should contain the long string is empty. Why is that and how do I take advantage of the 2GB limit that I read about?

This is the property in the linq-to-sql model:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All MAX datatypes--VARCHAR(MAX), NVARCHAR(MAX), and VARBINARY(MAX)--have a limit of 2 GB. There is nothing special you need to do.  Without specifying `MAX`, the limit for VARCHAR and VARBINARY are 8000 and the limit for NVARCHAR is 4000 (due to NVARCHAR being double-byte).  If you are not seeing any data come in at all, then something else is going on.

Are you sure that the column is even in the INSERT statement? If you submit test data of only 20 characters, does that get written?  If you want to see what SQL is actually submitted by Linq, try running SQL Profiler and look at the `SQL Statement: Statement Ended` event, I believe.

Also, when you say that the "long string is empty", do you mean an actual empty string or do you mean NULL?  If it is not NULL, you can also wrap the field in a LEN() function to see if there are blanks for returns at the beginning that push any non-whitespace characters out of view. Meaning, `SELECT LEN(stringField), * FROM Table`.  Another thing to try is to use "Results to Text" instead of "Results to Grid" (this is a Query option).

EDIT:
Seeing that the field is marked as NOT NULL, are you sure that you are setting the `ClientFileJS` property of your object correctly?  Is it possible that the empty string is due to that property being initialized as `string ClientFileJS = "";` and is never updated?

Comment: Everything in my code should work: when I artificially replace the long string with a short 10-character string, I can see the string in the DB. The write query is also wrapped in a try-catch statement and there also, nothing unusual happens and the catch is never triggered.

Comment: @frenchie: ok, so we are getting closer. Now that you can pass in a 10-character string, trying artificially passing in a longer string, maybe something that is 8010 characters, just to see if it works. If it doesn't, try reducing it to 7990.  If it does work, try increasing it to 100k.  Again, it could be the specific data being passed in or that property not being set correctly.

Comment: I got it! When you insert/update a field that's a long string and then open up the table in SSMS or in Visual Studio, the field will APPEAR empty but will actually be populated. You can click on the cell in SSMS and do a copy-paste of it in Notepad and the data in that cell will appear. The data is not visually visible but it's there. For this functionality, WHAT A BAD DESIGN for SSMS and Visual Studio!

Comment: @frenchie: I would be surprised if the data were _truly_ not there. That is why I suggested **copy/paste** and/or **Results To Text** to see if there are any leading white-space characters.